# Unhandled promise rejection for async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I am getting an **Unhandled promise rejection** warning for my **express backend.** I'm not entirely sure how to go about solving this as I've never worked with Express before.

```
//run function
function run(TrainLine, StartStation, EndStation,ArrivalTime,ArrivalDate) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var process = spawn('python3',["./python/main.py",
                            TrainLine,
                            StartStation,
                            EndStation,
                            ArrivalTime,
                            ArrivalDate
                            ] );

    const out = []
    process.stdout.on(
      'data',
      (data) => {
        out.push(data.toString());
        logOutput('stdout')(data);
      }
    );

    const err = []
    process.stderr.on(
      'data',
      (data) => {
        err.push(data.toString());
        logOutput('stderr')(data);
      }
    );

    process.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
      logOutput('exit')(`${code} (${signal})`)
      if (code !== 0) {
        reject(new Error(err.join('\n')))
        return
      }
      try {
        resolve(JSON.parse(out[0]));
      } catch(e) {
        next(e);
      }
    });
  });
}

app.post('/commuterequest',async function(request,response){
    console.log(request.body);

    const outputjson =await run(request.body.TrainLine,request.body.StartStation, request.body.EndStation, request.body.ArrivalTime, request.body.ArrivalDate);

    console.log(outputjson);

    response.json(outputjson);
});

app.get('/express_backend', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'connected to backend!' });
});
```

This is my run function code defined. I'm attempting to add the try catch to the original await function. I'm not quite sure how to do that given the syntax of the code.

**Full Error Message**

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'TrainLine' of undefined
    at C:\Users\mokas\Downloads\MTA_Crunch\server.js:62:49
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mokas\Downloads\MTA_Crunch\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\mokas\Downloads\MTA_Crunch\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\mokas\Downloads\MTA_Crunch\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mokas\Downloads\MTA_Crunch\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\mokas\Downloads\MTA_Crunch\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\mokas\Downloads\MTA_Crunch\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\mokas\Downloads\MTA_Crunch\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (C:\Users\mokas\Downloads\MTA_Crunch\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mokas\Downloads\MTA_Crunch\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Comment: add `try catch` on `await` function call

Comment: @YashRami Thanks for the help. I've been trying to add it but I don't think I'm doing it properly. How would try catch be added to await?

Comment: can you show your `run` function code

Comment: @YashRami I've added it as an edit in my original question

Comment: try like this 
`try {
        await run(...);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }`

Comment: @YashRami The code when implemented gave me the same error, do you think this could be originating from elsewhere?

Comment: might be possible you can refer this link https://alphacoder.xyz/nodejs-unhandled-promise-rejection-warning/#:~:targetText=If%20you%20didn't%20already,properly%20can%20crash%20your%20app! it may help you out

Answer (score 0):

Route handler of `Express` has 3 arguments. Third argument is optional argument which has a role to handle a rejected error of asynchronous handler. So you need to pass a rejected error to it.

```
app.post('/commuterequest',async function(request,response, next){
    console.log(request.body);

    try {
       const outputjson =await run(request.body.TrainLine,request.body.StartStation, request.body.EndStation, request.body.ArrivalTime, request.body.ArrivalDate);
       console.log(outputjson);

       response.json(outputjson);
    } catch (e) {
       next(e);
    }


});
```

Comment: The code when implemented gave me the same error, do you think this could be originating from elsewhere? I've added the error message in the original question

Comment: @RiyaMokashi I tested example code again, but it handled an error well. Could you share your modified code?